# RSS глючит? Десятками валится

Tags: дефект, rss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём только [по одному тегу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=eclipse&sort=newest), по другим всё в порядке. Формально между двумя обращениями вижу разницу только тут:

```
$ diff 1.rss 2.rss 
8c8
<     <updated>2018-03-12T04:43:44Z</updated>
---
>     <updated>2018-03-12T04:51:08Z</updated>
```

P.S У других потоков поле `updated` не меняется, если нет обновлений, только у этого.